# Combine overlapping observable streams but take most recent values

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've got a use case I've been trying to conquer with regards to combining streams using Rx. I've got 3 streams outputting values:

```
S1: ----1----2----3----4----5-----6
S2: ----a---------c---------d------
S3: ---------x---------y----------z
```

I want to combine (zip) streams 1 & 2 and 1 & 3, the logic being that both 2 & 3 can never output a value at the same time.

So the desired output is:

```
1,a
2,x
3,c
4,y
5,d
6,z
```

But what is actually happening is:

```
1,a
1,x
2,c
2,y
3,d
3,z
```

Any clues as to how I'd get the desired output?

Code:

```
Subject<int> s1 = new Subject<int>();
Subject<string> s2 = new Subject<string>();
Subject<string> s3 = new Subject<string>();

var zip1 = s1.Zip(s2, (x, y) => {
    return new Tuple<int, string>(x, y);
});

var zip2 = s1.Zip(s3, (x, y) => {
    return new Tuple<int, string>(x, y);
});

zip1.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
zip2.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));

s1.OnNext(1);
s2.OnNext("a");

s1.OnNext(2);
s3.OnNext("x");

s1.OnNext(3);
s2.OnNext("c");

s1.OnNext(4);
s3.OnNext("y");

s1.OnNext(5);
s2.OnNext("d");

s1.OnNext(6);
s3.OnNext("z");
```

Comment: Will s2 and s3 always alternate, or can one output multiple values in a row with the other outputting none in that timespan?

Comment: s2 and s3 can output multiple values in a row any number of times, so there is no pattern.

Comment: What should happen if s1 output multiple values without s2 or s3 outputting any?

Comment: I hadn't really thought that far, realistically I'd try and code it so that scenario could never happen.

Answer (score 1):

For each of the streams that you have, s2 and s3, you can create a `Subject`, subscribe to the original stream, and then pass the value onto the new `Subject` after awaiting for the next value of `s1`:

```
var zip1 = new Subject<Tuple<int, string>>();
s2.Subscribe(async value =>
{
    var other = await s1.FirstAsync();
    zip1.OnNext(Tuple.Create(other, value));
});

var zip2 = new Subject<Tuple<int, string>>();
s3.Subscribe(async value =>
{
    var other = await s1.FirstAsync();
    zip2.OnNext(Tuple.Create(other, value));
});
```

You've stated that you're going to manage the timings of the streams such that one value is yielded from `s1` for each value of the other streams combined.  If you do manage that, you'll be fine.  If there are multiple values yielded from `s1` without any corresponding value in another stream, it'll be ignored, and if multiple values are yielded from the other streams combined without a corresponding value in `s1` then the next value yielded out of `s1` will be repeated.

There is another option that's a bit more contrived, but that is more flexible in the timings between values.  This approach is to first project each stream into something that holds the value but that distinguishes it from the other streams.  The streams can then be merged, zipped with `s1`, and then multiple streams can be created that filter out the values for each particular stream.  These then will need to be projected back to the original values.

```
var zip = s2.Select(s => Tuple.Create(1, s))
    .Merge(s3.Select(s => Tuple.Create(2, s)))
    .Zip(s1, Tuple.Create);

var zip1 = zip.Where(pair => pair.Item1.Item1 == 1)
    .Select(pair => Tuple.Create(pair.Item2, pair.Item1.Item2));
var zip2 = zip.Where(pair => pair.Item1.Item1 == 2)
    .Select(pair => Tuple.Create(pair.Item2, pair.Item1.Item2));
```

If you don't actually need separate streams, and only want to replicate the output as a single stream, it's actually *much* simpler:

```
var output = s1.Zip(s2.Merge(s3), Tuple.Create);
output.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
```

Comment: Yes I was going to post what you have in your final one line Zip+Merge snippet.  Based on the marble diagram and the description that line trivially solves the problem.

Comment: @Brandon That assumes he doesn't need separate streams, and only needs the one combined stream.  It's certainly the nicest solution if that's what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Is this not just a case of doing this?

```
var query =
    s1.Zip(s2.Merge(s3),
        (x, y) => new Tuple<int, string>(x, y));
```

I get this result given your code provided in the question:

[image: results]

Comment: Definitely closer to the solution I need. Problem is that s2 and s3 won't necessarily know about each other.

Comment: @David - Then your sample code is a special case. I think you'd need to provide some more realistic code to illustrate your needs.